# How to increase integer field in List of objects

Tags: java

well, I have `List<HighscoreEntry>` In which your class is this:

```
public class HighscoreEntry {
    private List<String> users;
    private int score;

    HighscoreEntry(List<String> users, int score) {
        this.users = users;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public List<String> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<String> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

Well, what happens, is because in the other class I have this:

```
public class ScoreboardItemData {
private final static HighscoreComparator comparator = new HighscoreComparator();
private final List<HighscoreEntry> entries;
private final Map<String, Integer> points;
private int scoreType;
private int clearType;

public ScoreboardItemData(int scoreType, int clearType, List<HighscoreEntry> entries, Map<String, Integer> points) {
    this.scoreType = scoreType;
    this.clearType = clearType;
    this.entries = entries;

    this.points = points;
}

public List<HighscoreEntry> getEntries() {
    return this.entries;
}

public Map<String, Integer> getPoints() {
    return this.points;
}

public void addEntry(List<String> users, int score) {
    synchronized (this.entries) {
        this.entries.add(new HighscoreEntry(users, score));

        this.entries.sort(comparator);
    }
} }
```

Well, I already can add new entries, but I want to change **ONLY THE SCORE** and increase it, to existing data.

And I tried some things, but without success:

**Example 1**:

```
synchronized (this.entries) {
        for (int i = 0;i < this.entries.size(); i++) {
            if (this.entries.get(i).getUsers() == users) {
                this.entries.get(i).increaseScore(score);
                this.entries.sort(comparator);
            } else {
                this.entries.add(new HighscoreEntry(users, score));
                this.entries.sort(comparator);
            }
        }
    }
```

This example update the score, but with the loop, he will add more entries and update others, so will always do this loop.

**Example 2**:

```
HighscoreEntry entry = (HighscoreEntry) this.entries.stream().filter((x) -> {
        return x.getUsers().equals(users);
    });
    if (entry.getUsers() != null) {
        entry.increaseScore(score);
    } else {
        entry.setUsers(users);
        entry.setScore(score);
    }
```

And this one, return this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 cannot be cast to com.heraproject.wired.data.ScoreboardItemData$HighscoreEntry
at com.heraproject.wired.data.ScoreboardItemData.addEntry(ScoreboardItemData.java:45)
```

Comment: @AntoineB The problem is: I already tried with replaceAll, set and other things to change the existing data, but none of them helped!

Comment: show what you've tried, I can't seem to make sense of what you're asking.

Comment: @Aomine I've added a few examples that I used and did not succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the right item in the list based on the identifier and looking at HighscoreEntry that identifier is `users`. This code will update the score for a HighscoreEntry in the list entries if one exists

```
public void addScore(List<String> users, int score) {
    HighscoreEntry entry = entries.filter( e -> (e.getUsers().equals(users))).findFirst().orElse(null);
    if (entry != null) {
        entry.setScore(score);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, his is what I want actually, but it did not work for me, because in the `(entry -> (entry.getUsers().equals(users)))` the **entry** return the error: "Variable 'entry' is already defined in the scope". But yeah, you understood what I really want. And tried to change the variable, but doesn't work

Comment: @RaphaLeão, I got that error to but forgot to update my answer before. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all you need is something like this

```
    // int index, someInt;
    this.entries.get(index).setScore(someInt);
```

However, looking at your model, I would think "high score" would be calculated by iterating over a list of potential `User` objects, each having their own unique scores. Then you set the score on the user, not the entity holding a list of users.

Comment: Yes, and to do this 'index' I will need to do an `for (int i = 0;i < this.entries.size(); i++)`, but still not working

Comment: It's not clear what you've done inside the loop or where/when you're looking at the updated score board

Comment: I'll put one example of code on main post to avoid mess here xD

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Use this method

```
public void updateEntry(List<String> users, int index) {
    synchronized (this.entries) {
        HighscoreEntry highScoreEntry = this.entries.get(index);

        highscoreEntry.setScore(//Update score);
        entries.add(index, highscoreEntry);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ya, but will update all entries, I want to update determined score of users I tried the solutions which u guys offered me, but none of them was the right solution

Comment: If you want so please use entry to loop with ArrayList find desired item and update score